# import module in parent and child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a parent class which `import _ from lodash` and then another class which is imported in the parent class also `import _ from lodash`. So will the bundled js will have lodash code twice.

```
//Parent Class
import Component from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Child from './Child';
class Parent extends Component{
   // using lodash here
} 

// Child class
import Component from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
class Child extends Component{
   // using lodash here
}
```

I am using webpack to bundle code .. will bundled file will have lodash code twice? 
How to understand imports ?
If it is so .. how to prevent this from happening? 
I think modules are imported only once, even if it is imported twice ..only single instance of it will exist? is it true?

Comment: Why don't you just inspect your bundle size?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ohhh.. I haven't thought about that ..thanx a lot for enlightenment. Will check.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack 3 or higher instantly runing deduplication algoritms when process bundling. 
If you use webpack < 2 you can use `new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()` in `plugins` configuration.

I recommend you to import lodash functions by this example, because you can load only necessary functions and reduce bundle memory use:

```
import { isEmpty, findIndex } from 'lodash';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import findIndex from 'lodash/findIndex';
```

Comment: DedupePlugin is not even needed because `lodash` refers to same package in both modules.

Comment: There's a typo, `isEmpty`.

Comment: @estus, hmmm, where?  `_.isEmpty(value)`  - it is from lodash website?

Comment: @ArtemMirchenko so lodash will be imported twice ..but webpack will remove duplicate code ?

Comment: @Uchit Kumar as far as correct me @estus `lodash` refers to same package in both modules. Also webpack dedupe your modules too. I edit my answer, there is correct `lodash` importing.